# How to set properties using Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Instead of doing this horrible loop which does achieve the desired result :

```
foreach (var mealsViewModel in mealsListCollection)
            {
                foreach (var VARIABLE in mealsViewModel.Items)
                {
                    foreach (var d in VARIABLE.ArticlesAvailable)
                    {
                        d.ArticleQty = 0;

                    }

                }
            }
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result but with this linQ statement    :

```
mealsListCollection.ForEach(u =>
                u.Items.Select(o => o.ArticlesAvailable.Select(c =>
                {
                    c.ArticleQty = 0;
                    return c;
                })));
```

But the linQ statement does not reset `ArticleQty` to zero

What I am doing wrong? and why ?

Comment: because `Select()` method does not iterate over collection

Comment: you need somethig like this: `mealsListCollection.ForEach(u => u.Items.ForEach(i => i.ArticlesAvailable.ForEach(c => c.ArticleQty = 0)))`

Comment: Use MoreLinq's `ForEach` - https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ForEach.cs - instead of `Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your linq to `ForEach` cause `Select` does not iterate through `collection` in the way you want.
MSDN definition:-

> `Select` Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.
>
> `ForEach` Performs the specified action on each element of the List.

```
mealsListCollection.ForEach(u => 
     u.Items.ForEach(o => 
     o.ArticlesAvailable.ForEach(c =>
     {
         c.ArticleQty = 0;
     })));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is: select is returning your same collection, but has no effect until the objects are iterated over. Sitting in the foreach call, the selects are outside of the execution path. (Review comments for more information).

.select() in a call by itself does nothing special but determine what the returned list will look like. 
.select().ToList() iterates over the collection, applying the projection.

If you were to set a variable equal to the .select call, but never access the data inside it, then the values would essentially still be what they started as. As soon as you iterate over, or select a specific element, it would then apply the projections.

Changing the selects to foreachs per vasily's comments will give you the desired results.

Can I perhaps suggest that you look to set the value equal to 0 further up your stack ( or down)? - Without knowing your use case, maybe there Is a better place to default it back to 0 than where you have chosen?
 (automapper, Initializer, etc )

Comment: This is totally worng. `Select()` is not creating anything. More of that, where do you see, that OP is creating _"a new obect with the 0 property"_? There is a `ToList()` method, that actually create a new **List** of the **same** objects (for reference type).

Comment: Checkout the microsoft docs at the link provided below. Although I am using the word create, which it looks like you do not approve of, it is satisfying the return type of the select statement that OP is calling. There is, above, a new answer where the owner points out that this is infact a projection, which is described in the below link as well. Yes, you are correct in that op is not calling .ToList(), good call out. Thank you for that. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You don't get my point. Read the **Remarks** section of your link. `Select()` does nothing with collection or collection items it self. It will never create/edit/update/transform anything.

Comment: Setting object returned from `Select()` to a variable means nothing too. This line `collection.Select(i => i.Value = 0);` and this `var result = collection.Select(i => i.Value = 0);` will not change collection (projection function `i => i.Value = 0` actually will never be executed).

Comment: add to previous comment: `collection.Select(i => i.Value = 0).ToList();` will actually change `collection` items, eventhough I not assign it to any variable. The same result will be with `collection.Select(i => i.Value = 0).GetEnumerator();` and `foreach(var item in collection.Select(i => i.Value = 0));`.

Comment: I believe we are on the same page, re-reading the remarks section is only proving my point further.  Perhaps my wording is clear to me, but not to others, so I apologise for that. My answer is saying that his statement is returning a collection based on his original calling collection- in which he would have to assign to a new variable. That is what my first paragraph is about. 

But, based on your statement of it not creating, what if I did something like this : .select(x => new {prop1 = "new prop"});

That will create a new object for each of the items in the calling collection.

Comment: Return type of `ForEach()` is `void`, so about which statement do you talk? And no, `collection.Select(x => new { prop1 = "new prop" });` will not create any new collection or anything within existing collection. If you not iterate this, projection function code (`x => new { prop1 = "new prop" }`) will never be executed. But when you iterate this with, for example, `ToList()` call it his responsability to invoke projection function on every element in collection and build a list from results. It's how deferred execution works.

Comment: My answer is referring in direct to the ops select statement, not even worrying about the previous 2 forEacbs. It was going past me where you were getting caught up with my answer. But really, we are on the same page. In my setence 'not assigning it to anything' I was under the assumption the reader would know to iterate the select statement, that is the whole point of the select statement. I believe you blatantly saying I am wrong is invalid, and that my answer still satisfies the question being asked.

Comment: _"My answer is referring in direct to the ops select statement"_ - there is 2 select statements. _"not even worrying about the previous 2 forEachs"_ - there is 3 `foreach` loops and 1 `ForEach()` method call. So about which statement do you talk? _"I was under the assumption the reader would know to iterate the select statement"_ - OP don't knows that, this is the reason of his issue. And this is common problem actually (people forget to iterate `IEnumerable` all the time). I'm blatantly saying your answer is wrong, mostly because it's misleading (apart from the fact that it's wrong).

Comment: It doesn't matter what comes before the .select is all I'm trying to say. The use of select itself is the problem, which is why I keep saying we are on the same page. When op is iterating his solution (not shown in his limited post) he is expecting the .selects to execute applying the projection. This is not happening because in his foreach.select.select, the selects are outside of his execution path. I have edited the post as so it now makes sense. Please reevaluate.

Comment: I still can't understand what you mean by _"on the same page"_, but your answer is not misleading now, so I removed my downvote. Thanks for discussion, and I hope I was not too offencing (I did not mean to be rude at all).

Comment: Btw, I have tested performance of `foreach-loop-approach` and `ForEach()-method-approach`. First of all, generated IL-codes are different. Also DEBUG builds are performing the same, RELEASE build with `ForEach()-method-approach` is about 27% faster (I have test them over 100 000 000 of records).

Answer (score 0):

Use SelectMany to work through trees of nested lists. Use the ForEach function last to do the work:

```
mealsListCollection
.SelectMany(m => m.Items)
.SelectMany(i => i.ArticlesAvailable)
.ToList()
.ForEach(a => { a.ArticleQty = 0; });
```

Comment: `ForEach()` is an extension method for `List<T>`, not for `Enumerable<T>`. So you have to call `ToList()` right before `ForEach()`.